# Helical inserts on aerospace parts work intermittently

Tags: aerospace-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, machining, aluminum

I work at a machine shop with high-volume parts and a lot of threaded holes. Common sizes are 1/4-28 STI and 10-32 STI. Every hole gets a helical insert. We have always had major issues with the 1/4-28 STI holes. Some inserts will go in with no problem, some will not even go halfway in. These are holes that have been through the same process and tapped with the same tap. What can be some causes of this? Also, we never have problems with any other hole size. Just 1/4-28 STI. We use pneumatic drivers and also dip the inserts in a liquid before inserting.
also, every part gets anodized.

Started doing some research and testing. Like debris in the holes from buffing and tumbling, or anodizing thickness causing issues. These are all still in development.

Final questions:
Has anybody had similar problems and did you find a solution?
Does anodizing leave a thick enough layer to affect this?
What about Alodine?

Comment: Is there any consistency with what holes suffer from it? Perhaps always in the latter half of tool's life cycle? Or perhaps the inserts that don't go in are always part of the same batch? Or the anodization from the same batch? Or perhaps the guilty holes are only every in specific locations? Are the inserts removable? For example, if an insert does not go in, can you remove it and stick it in a hole where an insert has been previously confirmed to go in? And can you stick an insert that has been previously confirmed to go in a hole into the hole where the insert has previously not gone in?

Comment: the inserts cannot be removed without damaging them. I cant seem to see any consistancy.

Comment: With my research so far I'm leaning toward debris in the holes. We purchased a thread gage to use and off the machine the threads are good and after tumbling the threads are still good. In this case, we used compressed air to blow out all debris immediately after tumbling. I am now waiting on a part that has been tumbled but I am not going to blow out debris. I am going to let it dry (which is how they have been doing it due to high-volume parts). I am hoping that there will be debris in the part, meaning all we have to do is make sure the holes are super clean after each dirty process.

Comment: There will be a part with 10 holes. Some will go, some won't. It cant be tool-wear, cant be the wrong drill size. What other options are there besides dirty holes?

Comment: Would that not be simple enough to find out by cleaning out a hole where an insert previously had not gone in? Or is the part lost when an insert is botched? I guess that would explain all the trouble you're having if you can't ever verify anything.

Comment: In the event that an insert won't go to the desired depth, It has to be pulled out and the insert is mangled. We usually just retap the hole and the insert goes in fine. I think we just aren't keeping the holes clean. Some operators spray out each and every hole but it can be tedious, leaving room for the lazy operator to avoid doing it.

Comment: @Woody "lazy operator" or do you mean they are not really given sufficient time to clean each hole properly?

Comment: Easy enough to test by thoroughly cleaning the holes on a few parts and seeing if the issue goes away.

Comment: Just for grins, try installing steel plugs - grub screws - into the holes before tumbling. See if pulling the grub screws out after tumbling fixes the problem. The insert's starting bevel geometry may well be getting debris into the threads

Comment: @Phil, don't helioils have non-standard outer threads? Would it be possible to get a grub screw to suit?

Comment: @Transistor Thick walled inserts are different from helicoils. You can get all kinds of thread combos. They are normal fed into standard tapped holes.

Comment: I think there is plenty of time to blow out each hole on every part. While one part is running, they are buffing and then waiting. Regardless, the time lost due to reworking parts because the helicoils won't thread is more valuable. So far it looks like cleaning out the threads right after the part is machined (while still wet from the coolant) and right after tumbling (part still wet) has worked so far. Next week i will take a part that i know for sure has good clean threads and will anodize it to see if it changes anything.@SolarMike

Comment: I thought about the plugs but it would add way more time per part and I think we would just be worse off. Trying to shave time off the part not add.@PhilSweet

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this years ago. High-precision bearing balls; some fit and others did not. Turns out the vendor was shipping us parts which had been rejected as out-of-spec by his other customers. Our volumes were tiny compared to his bigger clients and this was his way of saying he didn't want our business.

We had to institute 100% incoming inspection for roundness and diameter on the balls to keep his junk out of our process- in essence, we were doing his quality control work for him. Do you have incoming inspection for the 1/4-28 STI parts?

Comment: We make the parts and have recently purchased a thread gauge to prove they are good holes. Also, the helical inserts are from large reputable companies that are sometimes even called out in a spec on drawing. Can't really get around it. Dont think this is the problem. @niels nielsen

Answer (score 0):

I'm an EE - so not very knowledgeable on this stuff - but have had a look at some of these helicoil devices. As far as I can see the action of screwing them in reduces the diameter if they bind on anything so they should free up as a result.

I'm wondering if they are being advanced inconsistently and binding vertically rather than diametrically? Are the pneumatic drivers too heavy? Could you cut a deep slot in the driver bit so that it bottoms out in the hole and the coil's driven "diameter" can slide down the slot at a rate determined by the thread rather than the weight of the driver?

What's your success rate if you drive them in by hand?

Comment: The drivers are on arms that are designed for repeatability (there is a counterbalance to keep it light. The practice used by us right now is placing the driver on the whole and resting it on the hole while driving the insert. The drivers are designed to have shims and we have them set to drive a certain, measured depth each time. We don't drive any by hand as it would be impractical. We put inserts in hundreds if not thousands of holes every day. Of course we can try it by hand if you suggest that will help in the troubleshooting process